# c# specflow read hidden html field value

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Specflow (C#) for automation scripts. I am trying to read hidden value (from Source). But I am getting the below error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Coypu.BrowserSession' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor'.'

Please see the below source code:

```
<h3>ZZZZ &#8211; AAAA</h3>
<div>


input type="hidden" name="ref" id="ref" value="A0D9E90861D96E-20180919073132"
```

Code I am using is

```
 var text = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_browser).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerText", _browser.FindId("ref"));
```

Note: At the client, we are using framework "CopyU" and it looks like it is causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. No need to use JavaScript...
In CopyU framework, ConsiderInvisbleElement is off. Just turned that On using the below and it picked up the value.

var Hiddenvalue = _browser.FindId("transactionReference", new Options { ConsiderInvisibleElements = true });
            var trasactionReference=Hiddenvalue.Value;